# how to write server timestamp in milliseconds to Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I know how to write the server timestamp to Firestore as a *date string*:

`doc_ref.set({ts: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()});`

but how can I store its unix timestamp as a number instead? Is this even possible? I need to be able to mirror a subset of my Firestore documents in Algolia and I don't believe I can sort an Algolia index by timestamp strings.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not being stored as a string in the document - that's just how it [serverTimestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue#.serverTimestamp) renders in the console.  If you examine the ts field more closely, you'll see that it has a type of "timestamp".  When you go to edit the value in the console by clicking it, you'll see the type a value clearly shown as a date type.  When you read it back out (in JavaScript), you'll get a Date object back, and you can get the unix epoch-based time from that.

Comment: Ok so to clarify,  it's not possible to store the time stamp as a number?

Comment: A timestamp *is* a number.  The console is showing you a string form, and the API is giving you a Date, which is just a wrapper around a number.

Comment: Alright,  i just think there should be an option to set a field value as something like the .sv timestamp object in the RTDB so a straight number is stored, where no wrapping/unwrapping of the date object is necessary.

Comment: If you'd like to request the option that the console show its raw value, I'd [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Comment: @DougStevenson Is this still how it works? Firestore recently changed their date storage etc. I don't know how to currently get a `new Date()` from a firestore `serverTimestamp()`. Do you?

Comment: @mesqueeb you can use `toDate()` on the serverTimestamp object. See [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#todate)